# multiple variation of a domain to one domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was trying to write code for permanent redirect of multiple variations 
For eg.

```
http://www.example.com
http://example.com

http://www.example.com/index.php

http://example.com/index.php
```

to `https://example.com`only.

I have few lines of code

```
 RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Its working fine for me but Can these all lines of code be written in single or two lines??

Comment: This better fits https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com. As this is already a working code and you just wish to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com$`, without any `^`.

This should cover both your first and second HTTP_HOST lines.

The HTTP_HOST third line that you have, with `/index.php` in it is a bad one, as `/index.php` is never part of the HTTP_HOST.

Also don't keep repeating `RewriteEngine On` and no need to set a condition on port 80. (If you have HTTPS on port 443, you still want this redirect, right?)

So in the end:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Probably better to have `(.+\.)?example.com` to prevent something like `somexample.com` from matching